# PHP CURL Yahoo Finance Returning Blank

Tags: php, curl, rss

Trying to get some data from Yahoo Finance RSS feed, but when using curl I get a blank response. Anyone know why?

```
function getContents($thisURL) {
$strURL = "$thisURL";
$resURL = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strURL); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}


$feed = getContents("http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=AAPL&region=US&lang=en-US");
```

If I use regular file_get_contents it works no problem such as:

```
file_get_contents("http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=AAPL&region=US&lang=en-US");
```

I don't want to use file_get_contents

Comment: Use **curl_error** to see the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `curl` function contains several errors, this works (tested):

```
<?php
function getContents($thisURL) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $thisURL);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

echo getContents("http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=AAPL&region=US&lang=en-US");
?>
```

---

Everything that I removed from you function was wrong or unnecessary. I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);`

---

You can read more about the [curl function on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: The resource loads fine in browser, but I'm getting a 301 error when using your method. *Edit:* Debugging local env settings

Comment: I've tested the code and it works fine, no idea of what can be wrong on your side.

Comment: Well, I like to gzip traffic + there is sometimes significant increase in speed with using v4, but besides that it's perfect, thank you so much. Will accept when it lets me in 1 minute.

Comment: Still getting the same problem after editing my php.ini and restarting Apache. Will update if I find anything. *Edit:* Literally no idea what's happening. Probably a firewall issue. Works on a remote server otherwise. Nice answer!

Comment: In the future, use `curl_error($ch)` before `curl_close($ch);` to find the error.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Pedro, I really do appreciate.